Simulated Annealing
I want to build an ionic liquid monolayer on a metal surface. For that, I am planning to use simulated annealing method. However, I am not finding appropritate literature regarding the same. Can anyone help regarding the same? Also, any help regarding how to build this particular system will be really useful. Thank you in advance.

I don't really understand the issue here, have you tried searching for "simulated annealing" and an MD code? My first two hits are: https://winmostar.com/en/tutorials/V8/LAMMPS_tutorial_3(Polymer_Annealing)V8.pdf and http://docs.openmm.org/latest/userguide/application/04_advanced_sim_examples.html
